# Validation on input field using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, validation

I wants to check, if entered field's value is valid or not using onchange before submitting the page. I have written like below.It validates well.But how to activate 'NEXT' button  when there is no error on input entries.

```
<div><input type="text" name="your_name" id="your_name" onchange = "validate_Name(this,1,4)" />
   <span id="your_name-error" class="signup-error">*</span>
</div>
<div><input type="text" name="your_addr" id="your_addr" onchange = "validate_Name(this,1,4)" />
   <span id="your_addr-error" class="signup-error">*</span>
</div>
<input class="btnAction" type="button" name="next" id="next" value="Next" style="display:none;">

<script type="text/javascript" src="../inc/validate_js.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#next").click(function() {
            var output = validate(); //return true if no error
            if (output) {
                var current = $(".active"); //activating NEXT button

            } else {
                alert("Please correct the fields.");
            }
        });
    }

    function validate() {
        //What should write here?I want to analyse the validate_js.js value here.
    }
</script>
```

Inside validate_js.js

```
function validate_Name(inputVal, minLeng, maxLeng) {

    if (inputVal.value.length > maxLeng) {
        inputVal.style.background = "red";
        inputVal.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = "<br>Max Characters:" + maxLeng;
    } else if (!(tBox.value.match(letters))) {
        inputVal.style.background = "red";
        inputVal.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = "<br>Use only a-zA-Z0-9_ ";
    } else {
        inputVal.style.background = "white";
        inputVal.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "activating" you want to make it visible, you can call `$('#next').show()`.

However if you want to simulate a click on it, with jQuery you can simply call `$('#next').click()` or `$('#next').trigger('click')` as described [here](https://api.jquery.com/click/#click). Also, you might want to put everything in a form and programmatically submit the form when the input passes validation.

Comment: this is not my doubt.How to check there is error before activate or deactivate next button

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're facing? What does not work?

Comment: validation when onchange and activating next button are working fine.I want to check the validation when clicking on Next button too.That is, How to stop activating Next button when there is any invalid fields?

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly trigger the `change` event for each field so it validates each one again.

eg.

```
function validate() {
    $("#your_name").trigger('change');
    $("#your_addr").trigger('change');
}
```